# Background-color of UITabBarItem?(Swift/xCode)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationbar, tabbar

I try to change the background-color of my `UITabBarItems` to get away these ugly green borders around the icons

[image: see picture]

The problem is away when i comment out this line in my `AppDelegate`:

```
UIView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.12, green: 0.67, blue: 0.478, alpha: 1)
```

I have tried several things but it seems that there is no chance to do it when I want a green `UIView` background and a light black navigation bar with white icons and font.

This are the Settings for my `UITabBar`. Changing the translucent from true to false did not solve the problem..

[image: This]

Comment: I think the problem is in your tab bar images. Can you add that twitter icon to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Through code i tried to change this it works .
Just try this lines of code ( by specifying your own color ) :

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.tintColor    = UIColor.white

self.tabBarController?.tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.white

self.tabBarController?.tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = UIImage.imageWithColor(color: UIColor.blue,size: tabBarItemSize).resizableImage(withCapInsets: .zero)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your help but my failure was at the line at AppDelegate. I fixed the problem by setting the backgroundColor new at every ViewController. :-)